# NodeJS highchart save png

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts, png

I am trying to use this code to save image into test.png file.

```
var request = require('request');

var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

var dataString = '{"infile":{"title": {"text": "Steep Chart"}, "xAxis": {"categories": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]}, "series": [{"data": [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]},"outfile":"test.png"}';

var options = {
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:7801',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: dataString
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
}

request(options, callback);
```

Please let me know what is wrong with this code. The outfile test.png is not getting generated.

Comment: this code sends some data to a server. what this server do, is unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image should be in the `body` object in your `callback` function (I assume that your server works properly).

Now you need to save it your file system. It can be done like this:

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
  require("fs").writeFile("out.png", body, 'base64', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
  console.log(error);
}
```

I added the flag in the `dataString` for `base64` encoding (`b64`). I had some encoding issues while receiving binary file so I used `base64` and it works fine.

```
var dataString = '{"infile":{"title": {"text": "Steep Chart"}, "xAxis": {"categories": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]}, "series": [{"data": [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]},"outfile":"test.png", "b64": true}';
```

You can find more information about this flag in **the API**: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/master/README.md